# Minimal dir-tree diffing with git

Tags: git

I was trying to see if I could coax git to diff plain directory trees (without involving all the commit-related stuff):

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
olddir=${1%/}
newdir=${2%/}
patch=$3
: "${patch:=$newdir--$olddir.gdiff}"

export GIT_DIR GIT_WORK_TREE

trap  'rm -rf "$tmpd"' EXIT
tmpd="$(mktemp -d)"
GIT_DIR="$tmpd"
git init --bare 
GIT_WORK_TREE="$olddir"; git add -A .; t0="$(git write-tree)"
GIT_WORK_TREE="$newdir"; git add -A .; t1="$(git write-tree)"

#git diff-tree --minimal "$t0" "$t1" 
git diff-tree --patch --binary --minimal "$t0" "$t1" > "$patch"
```

The script works but what bugs me about it is that if the newer tree deletes say a big binary file, the diff will say something like:

```
deleted file mode 100644
index a4cb08553c82100cd473bf9fcbbf4232038838dd..0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GIT binary patch
literal 0
HcmV?d00001

literal 250585
```

and then go on to include an **ASCII dump of the whole deleted file**. 
Not very "minimal". Can I get it to skip this info in the diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's diffs are intended to be fully reversible, and as such, any deleted file must show the deleted contents.  Using `--binary` tells Git to include binary files in patches, so this leaves you two options:

- omit `--binary` so that Git omits binary files, and/or
- tell `git diff` to produce an *irreversible* diff, using `--irreversible-delete` (or the short form of this, `-D`).  Note that this affects all deletions, not just binary files.

The irreversible delete option was new in version 1.7.10.

(Incidentally, note that `--minimal` merely switches from the default `myers` diff algorithm to one that attempts to produce fewer edit directives.)